# An error occurs when executing the multipath -f command in the Controller when creating a openstack-cinder volume

Tags: lvm, openstack, multipath, cinder

An error occurs when executing the multipath -f command in the Controller when creating a cinder volume.

==============Infrastructure configuration================

[Openstack Controller01] <----------> [Hitachi SAN Storage(FC)]

=========================================================

===============cinder-volume.log (Summary)==============

copy_image_to_volume: exception (81247ms)
Chained Exception #1
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/openstack/venvs/cinder-27.1.0/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cinder/volume/driver.py", line 532, in _detach_volume
connector.disconnect_volume(attach_info['conn']['data'],
File "/openstack/venvs/cinder-27.1.0/lib/python3.10/site-packages/os_brick/utils.py", line 185, in trace_logging_wrapper
result = f(*args, **kwargs)
File "/openstack/venvs/cinder-27.1.0/lib/python3.10/site-packages/os_brick/initiator/connectors/base.py", line 78, in inner
return f(*args, **kwargs)
File "/openstack/venvs/cinder-27.1.0/lib/python3.10/site-packages/os_brick/utils.py", line 387, in change_encrypted
res = func(**call_args)
File "/openstack/venvs/cinder-27.1.0/lib/python3.10/site-packages/os_brick/initiator/connectors/fibre_channel.py", line 392, in disconnect_volume
raise exc  # type: ignore
os_brick.exception.ExceptionChainer:
Chained Exception #1
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/openstack/venvs/cinder-27.1.0/lib/python3.10/site-packages/os_brick/initiator/connectors/fibre_channel.py", line 372, in disconnect_volume
self._linuxscsi.flush_multipath_device(mpath_path)
File "/openstack/venvs/cinder-27.1.0/lib/python3.10/site-packages/os_brick/initiator/linuxscsi.py", line 383, in flush_multipath_device
self._execute('multipath', '-f', device_map_name, run_as_root=True,
File "/openstack/venvs/cinder-27.1.0/lib/python3.10/site-packages/os_brick/executor.py", line 55, in _execute
result = self.__execute(*args, **kwargs)
File "/openstack/venvs/cinder-27.1.0/lib/python3.10/site-packages/os_brick/privileged/rootwrap.py", line 172, in execute
return execute_root(*cmd, **kwargs)
File "/openstack/venvs/cinder-27.1.0/lib/python3.10/site-packages/oslo_privsep/priv_context.py", line 271, in _wrap
return self.channel.remote_call(name, args, kwargs,
File "/openstack/venvs/cinder-27.1.0/lib/python3.10/site-packages/oslo_privsep/daemon.py", line 215, in remote_call
raise exc_type(*result[2])
oslo_concurrency.processutils.ProcessExecutionError: Unexpected error while running command.
**Command: multipath -f /dev/disk/by-id/dm-uuid-mpath-360060e802132f400506032f400000018
Exit code: 1
Stdout: ''
Stderr: '3043.060840 | 360060e802132f400506032f400000018-part2: map in use\n'**

=============================================================

When I checked with lsblk, it seems that the multipath cannot be deleted because the created volume contains lvm information.

===============lsblk information========
NAME                                      MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE
MOUNTPOINTS

loop0                                       7:0    0 111.9M  1 loop /snap/lxd/24322

loop1                                       7:1    0  63.5M  1 loop  /snap/core20/2015

loop2                                       7:2    0  40.9M  1 loop  /snap/snapd/20290

sda                                         8:0    0 893.3G  0 disk

├─sda1                                      8:1    0   512M  0 part

/boot/efi

└─sda2                                      8:2    0 892.7G  0 part  /

nbd0                                       43:0    0     0B  0 disk

nbd1                                       43:32   0     0B  0 disk

nbd2                                       43:64   0     0B  0 disk

nbd3                                       43:96   0     0B  0 disk

nbd4                                       43:128  0     0B  0 disk

nbd5                                       43:160  0     0B  0 disk

nbd6                                       43:192  0     0B  0 disk

nbd7                                       43:224  0     0B  0 disk

**360060e802132f400506032f400000018         253:0    0    41G  0 mpath
├─360060e802132f400506032f400000018-part1 253:1    0     1G  0 part
└─360060e802132f400506032f400000018-part2 253:2    0    36G  0 part**

**├─vg_main-lv_root                       253:3    0    32G  0 lvm**

**└─vg_main-lv_swap                       253:4    0     4G  0 lvm**

nbd8                                       43:256  0     0B  0 disk

nbd9                                       43:288  0     0B  0 disk

nbd10                                      43:320  0     0B  0 disk

nbd11                                      43:352  0     0B  0 disk

nbd12                                      43:384  0     0B  0 disk

nbd13                                      43:416  0     0B  0 disk

nbd14                                      43:448  0     0B  0 disk

nbd15                                      43:480  0     0B  0 disk

======================================================================

I would like to inquire if there is a way to create a cinder volume without lvm information.

Thank you for your help